# Determine version of JRE containing a fix from the Sun bug database

Tags: java, sun

**Updated**

Take https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6857057. We witnessed this in JRE 6u17. How do I know which version of the JRE contains the fix? The general consensus on the Internet seems to be 6u18 - but how can I tell this from the bug database? It says fixed in 6u16-rev, but I don't know what '-rev' means. Also it says it still affects version 6u18 - so is there some time dilation going on?

**Note**

Originally I assumed I'd need to build against a newer version of the JDK, so asked how I'd know which version of the JDK contained the fix. I've updated the question based on mindas explaining its actually the JRE which contains the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between **static** and **dynamic** linking. In Java world, all JVMs are obliged to load classes as they are referenced. In other words, your code which was compiled against older JDK version does not have the information about how older JDK implemented a particular method.

Unless the method signature has changed (from your bugs.sun.com link I assume it hasn't), you should not need to rebuild your classes. Even if it had, you would be getting a different error (something like `NoSuchMethodException`).